# How do I calculate no. of visits to a page with in a session (for the mentioned case) using sql (specifically teradata)?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have an events' table which has page id and event number with in that session as columns. How can I get the no. of visits to a page in a session?
For example, considering the below data no. of visits to p1 should be 2 and for p2 it should be 1.

`page_id   event_number
p1  1
p1  2
p1  3
p2  4
p2  5
p2  6
p1  7
p1  8
p1  9`

Answer (score 0):

Use the query as:

```
Select Page_Id, Count(event_number) as Visits Group by Page_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, 
       CASE 
         WHEN a.page_id <> b.page_id 
               OR b.page_id IS NULL THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END                     AS ind, 
       Sum(ind) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY a.page_id 
           ORDER BY a.seq_num) AS val 
FROM   testing_visits a 
       LEFT JOIN testing_visits b 
              ON a.seq_num + 1 = b.seq_num;
```

Credits to my friend, SreeRam Srinivasan.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer :

```
select page_id,
COUNT(page_id) OVER (PARTITION BY page_id ORDER BY page_id) 
FROM a
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the expected result as an aggregate:

```
SELECT page_id, COUNT(*)
FROM 
 (
   SELECT page_id, 
      CASE -- return 1 whenever there accessed page changes
         WHEN page_id = 
                MIN(page_id) 
                OVER (ORDER BY event_number
                      ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
         THEN 0 
         ELSE 1
      END AS flag
   FROM tab
   QUALIFY flag = 1 -- only return the 
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1
```

If you want to keep the detail rows simply switch to a `SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY page_id)` instead of `COUNT` and remove the `QUALIFY`.